# Typescript for Facebook React

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I've been looking into [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) lately and was hoping to use JSX and typescript. I haven't been able to find any resources on this or type definitions for [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/).

Can you use Typescript with JSX and are type definitions available?

Comment: The general problem with transpilers and JSX is that either the transpiler need to understand or pass the JSX code, or jsx needs to understand or pass the Typescript code, so its a lot of work to get there.

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/759

Comment: Facebook's Flow works as an alternative to TypeScript and supports JSX and ES6.

Comment: Until it is officially shipped, you can give it a try: http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/07/05/using-jsx-react-with-typescript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React jsx will be available in upcomming TypeScript 1.6. Here's [more info](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3564).

Answer (score 8):

The React team is currently discussing making Typescript annotations an internally used thing.  This may be changing on the official for you, soon.

Comment: In the IRC channel, or in their release notes, or on their blog.

Unfortunately the wrong answer is marked accepted, by someone claiming incorrectly that there are ambiguity problems, so this will get overlooked.

Comment: Since I wrote this, there are newer, smarter places to look.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/759

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: old answer is no longer true. Typescript for some time supports separate syntax context with `.tsx` files, where it drops `<>` casting syntax in favor of JSX.

---

> It won't. There is a lot of ambiguity between TypeScript type casting syntax:
>
> ```
> (<foo>bar)
> ```
>
> And JSX inline XML syntax:
>
> ```
> (<foo>bar)</foo>)
> ```

Comment: Good point, but isn't that just giving up too easily? I'm sure there's all kinds of workarounds, from context-sensitive syntax parsing (something like, assume it's a React component, but if no end tag can be found, assume it's a type assertion) to writing TypeScript type assertions like e.g. `<<any>>bar` in .tsx files.

Comment: Looks like it's actually possible. Haven't ran it myself just yet so proceed with caution. https://github.com/fdecampredon/jsx-typescript

Comment: Yep, they simply thrown out `<Class> v` casting in favor of `v as Class` syntax for `.tsx` files.

Answer (score 4):

François de Campredon created a type definition for React: https://github.com/fdecampredon/react-observe-todomvc/blob/typescript/src/declarations/react.d.ts

It does not support JSX obviously, since it is another language with a syntax different from TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

Did some research and figured I'd answer my own question. It seems that the JSX compiler doesn't yet recognize typescript constructs (hopefully it will later).

Answer (score 2):

With regard to jsx:

You could split your react components into two files. The first one would contain everything except of the render function and can therefore be written in Typescript. The second one would just implement the render function using JSX. I know this is against the 'react way', but it solves that problem. You would have the strength of Typescript every except of the render function.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the following talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PTa9-PPVAc

It has a lot of pointers as to how to make React work with TypeScript.

Facebook also recently announced a project called [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) which also adds static typing to Javascript. Since they're both Facebook projects, it might be easier to use Flow than TypeScript when dealing with React.js.

Answer (score 1):

For `create-react-app` projects just start off with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` command.

For further reading: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

Now things seems have changed, from official Typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#introduction)

TypeScript supports embedding, type checking, and compiling JSX directly to JavaScript.

And [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) on how start a project directly with Typescript